# How to fix null error when I've already declared the variable

Tags: java, null

I am making a PVP RPG game and the display box comes out with "null" instead of the variable I have already declared.

I have declared the variable as the user's next input and stored that information in the variable. Then when I try to display the variable, it only shows "null",

```
System.out.println("Welcome, Player One and Player Two!");
    delay(1500);
    System.out.println("What is your name, Player One?");
    playerOne.name = userInput.nextLine();
```

I already declared playerOne as a new character(different class)

```
System.out.println("Your turn, " + playerOne.name+".");
    if (p1Swordgo == 1) {
```

This is the problem I'm coming up with. It is in the same main method and the variables are declared in the main method, and yes I imported scanner and declared the variable userInput

I expected it to be what the user typed in, but it came up with null. As I've said previous, it's in the same main method and nothing should go wrong, but it comes up with "null"

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Arena {

Random generator = new Random();



public static void main(String[] args) {

    Character playerOne = new Character(10,10,0);
    Character playerTwo = new Character(10,10,0);

    boolean P1hasClass = false;
    boolean P2hasClass = false;
    int p1Swordgo = 0;
    int p2Alchgo = 0;
    int p2Archgo = 0;


    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Welcome, Player One and Player Two!");
    delay(1500);
    System.out.println("What is your name, Player One?");
    playerOne.name = userInput.nextLine();
    delay(1000);
    System.out.println("Hello, " +playerOne.name +".");
    delay(1000);
    System.out.println("What is your name, Player Two?");
    playerTwo.name = userInput.nextLine();
    delay(1000);
    System.out.println("Hello, " +playerTwo.name +".");
    delay(1500);

countdown();

        System.out.println("Your turn, " + playerOne.name+".");
    if (p1Swordgo == 1) {
        if (p2Archgo == 1 || p2Alchgo == 1) {
            if (playerOne.move == 1){

                System.out.println("What do you want to do?" +'\n' +"1 = Move into range of " +playerTwo.name +'\n' +"2 = Heal" +'\n' +"3 = Forfeit");
                int P1Choice = userInput.nextInt();
                if (P1Choice == 1) {
                    playerOne.move --;
                    System.out.println(playerOne.move);
                }

            }



        }

    }





}
















public static void delay ( int time){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(time);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}

public static void countdown() {
    delay(500);
    System.out.println("Get ready to fight in 5,");
    delay(1000);
    System.out.println("4");
    delay(1000);
    System.out.println("3");
    delay(1000);
    System.out.println("2");
    delay(1000);
    System.out.println("1");
    delay(1000);
    System.out.println("Fight!");
    delay(750);
}
```

}

And then in a class called Character

```
public class Character {


public int strength;
public double health;
public int move;
public String name;


public Character(double health, int strength, int move) {

    this.health = health;
    this.strength = strength;
    this.name = name;
    this.move = move;

}
```

}

And in a class called SwordFighter

```
public class SwordFighter extends Character {

public SwordFighter() {
    super(60,15, 1);
}
```

}

And in a class called Archer

```
public class Archer extends Character{

public Archer() {
    super(45,20, 0);
}
```

}

And finally, in a class called Alchemist
    public class Alchemist extends Character {

```
public Alchemist() {
    super(50,15, 0);
}
```

}

Thank you for your patience, by the way

Comment: Post a **complete** minimal example reproducing the problem. We must be able to copy and paste it, compile it and run it, without having to make changes and guesses.

Comment: Do you want me to copy and paste the whole file, or just the two classes that would be needed to run what I copy and pasted? Sorry, I'm still in my first week of learning java and still don't know all the technical terms.

Comment: Post the most minimal possible code that reproduces the issue, but not less. As I said, we must be able to copy and paste it, compile it and run it, without having to make changes and guesses.

Comment: Post that as formatted code, in your question, not as comments. There is an edit link at the bottom of the question. And again, I repeat a third time: we must be able to copy and paste it, compile it and run it, without having to make changes and guesses.

Comment: This code is still not compilable. Three classes are missing to be able to compile it. Remove all the code that is irrelevant to the bug you're asking, and post code that is compilable. Then tell precisely what you're doing, what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Answer (score 1):

Once the two players have chosen their name and you have set it using `playerOne.name = userInput.nextLine();`, you assign a different object, with a null name, to `playerOne`:

```
 playerOne = new SwordFighter();
```

So, after this line has been executed, `playerOne.name` is null.

Comment: Ah ok, I haven't even thought of that, thank you so much.